# Typescript searching in an array of Objects

Tags: typescript

I am very new to Typescript
I am having an array of Objects as following :

```
[{"val":"fo", "meaning":"food"},{"val":"m", "meaning":"mother"},{"val":"f", "meaning":"father"}]
```

I usually have the `val` and I would like to get the `meaning` back.
I could probably do some usual loops to search through the array to see if my val v : `v == myObject[0].val`

However, it's not very ellegant, and I was wondering how could I improve my solution ?

Lodash may provide something I could use, but I am really not sure if that's a good lead.

Comment: `f` means `food` or `father`?

Comment: Typescript doesn't provide any extra methods

Comment: [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). `filter` has more broad support.

Comment: i think typescript does't provide any extra support to these type of problem.
Use lodash library filter method, e.g._.filter(array, {"val": "f"}); for better solution.